# Bootstrap is not applying in asp.net master page

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a master page in asp.net.

Below is complete .aspx file.

CSS is added to div tag using bootstrap. All links are given.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="apage.master.cs" Inherits="Website.apage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

        <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="Panel_Main" style="box-shadow: 0 0 02px blue;" class="panel panel-primary">

            <div id="Panel_Heading" class="panel-heading">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="text-left">
                                <h4 style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; color: #FFFFFF">MyWebsite</h4>

                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="childContainer" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to run with a child page. But css is not applied in browser.

I have another masterpage with same configuration which is working fine. But for this page, css is not applied.

Am I missing something here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

Your all Script & all Js Write in Outside the **asp:ContentPlaceHolder**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="Panel_Main" style="box-shadow: 0 0 02px blue;" class="panel panel-primary">

            <div id="Panel_Heading" class="panel-heading">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="text-left">
                                <h4 style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; color: #FFFFFF">MyWebsite</h4>

                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="childContainer" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great. Worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Just one note, the way it is set up above any JQuery scripts that are run on child pages will not work as the content placeholder is before the script declarations ie, JQuery will be used before the reference is loaded.

Always load your master page scripts before the content placeholder for the head